# Bashrc configuration: Unexpected EOF

Tags: bash

I was doing my first bashrc configuration, i searched online for examples and i tried to do this but it gives me those errors:

I removed the colors code for a better reading.

bash: /home/filippo/.bashrc: line 228: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
bash: /home/filippo/.bashrc: line 228: `    fi')$BYellow$PathShortcut$Color_Off'\$ "; \'

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

shopt -s histappend

HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

shopt -s checkwinsize

[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\W\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

if [ -f ~/.git-prompt.sh ]; then
    . ~/.git-prompt.sh
fi

if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

Color_Off="\[\033[0m\]" # Text Reset

Time12h="\t"
Time12a="\@"
PathShort="\W"
PathFull="\w"
NewLine="\n"1
Jobs="\j"

export PS1=$BGreen'\u@\h'$Color_Off'$(git branch &>/dev/null;\
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then \
    echo "$(echo `git status` | grep "nothing to commit" > /dev/null 2>&1; \
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then \
        # @4 - Clean repository - nothing to commit
        echo "'$Green'"$(__git_ps1 " (%s)"); \
    else \
        echo "$(echo `git status` | grep "to be committed" > /dev/null 2>&1; \
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "'$IPurple'"$(__git_ps1 " {%s}"); \
        else \
            # @5 - Changes to working tree
            echo "'$IRed'"$(__git_ps1 " {%s}"); \
        fi)
    fi) '$BYellow$PathShort$Color_Off'\$ "; \
else \
    # @2 - Prompt when not in GIT repo
    echo " '$BIBlue$PathShort$Color_Off'\$ "; \
fi)'
```

Comment: Try shellcheck.net. You have unbalanced quotes somewhere.

Comment: Consider using setting `PROMPT_COMMAND` to the name of a function that builds your `PS1` value incrementally, rather than trying to stuff arbitrary code into a single string.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
>  *) return;;
> ```

return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script

To locate more errors run your script with:

```
bash -x script.sh
```

Comment: `.bashrc` *is* sourced, although the exit status doesn't seem to be used to set `$?`.